# keep the rows which has to satisfy some constraints are kind of complex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

There is a dataframe, including a time column.  There may have several time periods, for instance,

```
2012-06-10 : 2012-6-20
2014-08-10 : 2014-10-11
```

What are the efficient approaches to get the sub-dataframe, whose time information does not belong to the above time periods

Comment: I think we can use sth such as as (condition 1) & (condition 2) to solve this problem, but maybe not very efficient

Comment: Can you clarify? What do you mean "sub-dataframe"?

Comment: The sub-dataframe just means the remaining rows whose time column information satisfies the specified constraints.